# How to get current logged in user session of vSphere web client with vim25.

Tags: java, apache-flex, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

We are using vSphere web client SDK 6.0 (HTML bridge) and trying to retrieve session with **com.vmware.vise.usersession.UserSessionService.getUserSession()**.

for code sample you can refer **vsphere-wssdk** example from **vsphere-client-sdk\html-bridge\samples**.

After injecting this interface in class **VmDataProviderImpl**, it will return proxy object of UserSessionService and **_userSessionService.getUserSession()** always returns **null**.

How will we get current logged in user session of vSphere web client with vim25.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

`_userSessionService.getUserSession()` can return `null` in a number of cases:

- you are calling the method from outside of an HTTP-handling thread (http-bio--exec-XXX in Tomcat). The behavior is like this since there is no way to understand what is the user that initiated the action.
- you are calling the method inside an HTTP-handling thread but the plugin does not have its WAR's session properly set up - for example if you've forgotten to define a `SessionManagementFilter` inside your WAR's web.xml.